# how to stop active storage rails 6 from deleting fixture attachment file during delete action tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

When starting with a seeded testing database aka fixtures, then using transactional tests. The database "resets" to the starting point for each test. This works great except when running a Test where a model with an active storage reference is deleted/purged. The file is deleted from local test storage and all other tests fail. The blob and attachment are reset but the file was purged from the file system. Is there a setting I can turn on that changes this? I have tried googling but have not found a decent error.

using Rails 6 / Rspec

Consider:

- before any tests are run a series of records are built (fixtures), Foo has_one attachment.(database state 0)
- run a delete test, say a controller tests which deletes a Foo and Active Storage purges it's file from local storage.
- after test is done database is reset to state 0. So Foo record is back and the active storage attachment and blob are restored too but the local file for that blob has not been restored.
- next set of tests run for that Foo and they fail because file does not exist.

Comment: What framework are you using for testing RSpec/Minitest/Other? Also, check out https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#discarding-files-created-during-tests to clean up files after the test run. Perhaps you'd do something opposite.

Comment: This is not about "cleaning up" tests but rather restoring deleted files.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your setup, but does this help? https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures